# IE11 compatibility mode breaks Spring Whitelabel error page

Tags: java, spring-mvc, internet-explorer, spring-boot

I have a weird problem with IE11 and Spring Boot (1.3.3).
When compatibility mode is activated for IE11, error pages are not displayed correctly. Instead a download window appears in the browser.

Here is how to reproduce the error:

**Spring Tool Suite:**

- Create a new "Spring Starter Project"
- Use default name
- Use dependency "Web"
- Finish
- Start the Spring Boot Application

**Internet Explorer 11:**

- Click "Tools-Symbol"
- "Compatibility View settings"
- Add "localhost"
- Close

When you open "localhost:8080" now the browser does not show a Spring Whitelabel error anymore. It asks you to download "8080" from "localhost". What a nonsense :-(

I think the problem is related to this bug: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3633
But here the user gets at least a default IE 404 error.

Unfortunately I have to use compatibility mode as "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View" is the browser default in our company...
Does anyone have an idea how I could work around that issue?

PS: I also tried setting `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=EDGE; text/html; charset=UTF-8" />` in a custom error page which didn't helper either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE sends a different list of `Accept: Content-Types` values via the HTTP request header field than e.g. Chrome does. I wasn't able to reproduce the strange download behaviour you described, but using different browsers I got different responses for the same request, too.

Using IE I received a `Content-Type: application/json` response 
and using Chrome it was a `Content-Type: text/html` response.

You've to tell the server what `Content-Type` shall be produced for your whitelabel error page. This can be done by overriding Spring Boot's default `ErrorController` like this:

```
@Controller
public class YourCustomController implements ErrorController{

    private static final String PATH = "/error";

    @RequestMapping(value = PATH, produces={"text/html"})
    public String error() {
        return "error";
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return PATH;
    }
}
```

That should do the trick. A new error controller that produces `Content-Type: text/html` instead of a wrong `Content-Type` which supposedly forced your browser into the download.

Depending on what Template Engine you use (if you use an MVC approach at all), be aware of configuration parameters `spring.<your engine>.content-type`, described in the [application properties appendix of the spring boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties).

Comment: Thanks. It works more or less ;-). Unfortunately there is one downside: I am exposing parts of my application as a REST-API. Here I do want an error as content-type application/json => this default behavior is unfortunately overwritten by the approach above. Nevertheless I will mark this answer as accepted as it is a viable workaround for the initial problem.

Comment: Glad to here that, but pitty that it works only more or less for you. To bypass the downside you could think about throwing a `YourCustomException` from within your REST Controllers and let a separate `@ControllerAdvice` handle your custom exception type via the `@ExceptionHandler({YourCustomException.class})` annotation. The ExceptionHandler method could then reply with `@ResponseBody YourCustomException` to create the answer in a JSON format. Let me know if you need a code example.